# cannot resolve symbol addHeaderView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-studio

first of all, I am new to both stackoverflow and also android, so please feel free to give me feedback not only on my question but also on the way it is asked.Thanks in advance.

But, now about the problem. I have a list view for which I am using a list fragment and above it I display the weekday and the date (above that there is some other stuff which should be of no concern for the matter).
Currently the XML looks like this just so you might get a better feeling of what I am talking about.

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="#ffdcdcdc">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/all_food_button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fffdfdfe"
        android:src="@drawable/all_food_button_1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/all_food_button_description" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/soup_button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffe8913b"
        android:src="@drawable/soup_button_1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/soup_button_description" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/meat_button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff8787e8"
        android:src="@drawable/meat_button_1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/meat_button_description" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/veggie_button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff95ba27"
        android:src="@drawable/veg_button_1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/veggie_button_description" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/side_dish_button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/side_dish_1"
        android:background="#ff8ab8e5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/side_dish_button_description" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/days_line"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/week_day_line_description" />


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/monday_string_dummy"
        android:id="@+id/weekdayText"
        android:textColor="#ffff0000"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="35dp" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/date_string_dummy"
    android:id="@+id/dateText"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="35dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="324dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffdcdcdc"
    android:id="@+id/listDishesContainer"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"></FrameLayout>
```

As on some screens the list view is relatively small at the bottom of the screen I wanted to add the date and day as a header to the list. I went on and found something that seemed to be very usefull for this matter the addHeaderView method. I looked at a few tutorials and adapted what I saw. The result looks like this.

```
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dishlist, container, false);

    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header_day_date, mListView ,false);

    // Set the adapter
    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.addHeaderView(header);
    // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return view;
```

the problem is now, that android studio can't seem to resolve the addHeaderView method and I really don't know or see what I am missing and I hope that someone on here is able to help me. I couldn't find anything about that matter anywhere else so I am asking here. If I missed anything you also need to know just let me know and I will add that information to the post. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Header view should be set before setting an adapter. Do you have a compile error or runtime exception?

Comment: Hey vokilam, thanks for the quick response. It is a compile error. What exactly do you mean by header view should be set before setting the adapter? mListView.addHeaderView(header) should be located before mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter)? because that unfortunately doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

You cast a list view to `AbsListView` which doesn't have this method. `addHeaderView` is a method of [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)). Also read the description to that method. It is said to add headers before setting an adapter.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was guessing it was something simple. I was using AbsListView because android studio generated this method for me. I just didn't see it. Thanks again :)